# Facial detection fails on iPhone photos only using dlib

Tags: python, .net, iphone, face-recognition, dlib

I've been using the dlib library to detect faces, testing on both Python and DotNet wrappers. Both produce the same bizarre issue: poor (low image quality, poor lighting, etc.) images pulled from the internet are almost always detected while photos shot from my iPhone with high quality/lighting are almost never detected.

I am completely certain that the faces shot on my iPhone are of higher quality than those pulled from the internet, yet regardless of how many times I change the lighting and camera angle of my iPhone shots the results are always the same. An occasional iPhone face is detected while the large majority of perfectly acceptable face shots go undetected. I'm at a complete loss, any ideas are much appreciated.

A sample of my relatively straightforward code is below.

```
from face_recognition import load_image_file, face_locations

faces = face_locations(load_image_file("foo.jpg"))
face_detected = len(faces) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution and figured I'd share it in case anyone has this specific problem in the future. Converting all images to grayscale fixed literally every undetected face in my dataset. I wrote this in C# instead of Python, but I will share anyway. It can be done using the Emgu.CV library and the following code:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(path_to_image);
Image<Gray, byte> grayscaleEmguImage = emguImage.Convert<Gray, byte>().Clone();
Bitmap grayscaleBitmapImage = grayscaleEmguImage.ToBitmap();
```

It's fast and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try deepface as well?

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
img = DeepFace.detectFace("foo.jpg")
```

It wraps several face detectors actually. Its default detector is mtcnn but you can still set the detector you want.

```
detectors = ['mtcnn', 'opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib']
DeepFace.detectFace("foo.jpg", detector_backend = detectors[0])
```

detectFace function return exception if a face could not be detected.